# Pass directory as command line argument and get a file list?

Tags: c, directory, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass an archive and directory name command line arguments and extract a list of files in the directory. In eclipse I'm using "-A [archive.a] [directory_name]",
but eclipse keeps trying to compile the test directory files. Any suggestions? Code sample below is a condensed version of my program:
[Edit: ok, I got it to compile by moving out of the working directory...buts it's crashing at the readdir command...any tips?]
[Edit: ok just found out I can manually parse the files so I guess this question is academic now. Thx all.]

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)                 
{      
    char **fileList = (char **)(malloc(sizeof(char *) * argc));
    output = argv[2];        //archive name
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(argv[3]);        //directory name

    int i = 0;
    while((dir = readdir(d) != NULL))
    {
        fileList[i] = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(dir->d_name)));
        fileList[i] = dir->d_name;        //extract file names into array of strings
        ++i;
    }
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j <= argc; ++j)
    printf("%s\n", fileList[j]);        //print out list of file names

    closedir(d);
}
```

Comment: Just a random observation: you don't need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C.

Comment: yeah, I think it's a failsafe measure in case you forgot to type void?

Comment: It's not a fail-safe measure. It's only safe if you've included `<stdlib.h>` to get the declarations of `malloc()` et al, and you compile with options to ensure that you are told if you call `malloc()` without a prototype in scope. Then it is harmless (but unnecessary). If you've not included `<stdlib.h>` and are not compiling with the options needed, the cast conceals a bug — the compiler assumes `malloc()` returns an `int` and casts the return value to the pointer. I use casts; I compile with options to make sure I don't run into problems. You run risks if you're not as disciplined as I am.

Comment: (I might add that I learned to program on a pre-standard C system where if you had not declared `malloc()`, you got a core dump anyway, and you had to convert the `char *` that was returned by `malloc()` explicitly with a cast — or you got a core dump.  The early training by core dump still survives...I always ensure `malloc()` is declared.)

Comment: Is d `NULL`? You're not checking the return value.

Comment: `fileList[i] = malloc(1 + strlen(dir->d_name) );` and don't forget to copy. Or: `fileList[i] =  strdup(dir->d_name);` which will do the copying for you too.